# Removing multiple properties

Tags: javascript

Currently I'm using this minor bit of javascript to remove a small list of properties from a single page.

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  $('p').remove('.field-css-classes');
  $('p').remove('.field-description');
  $('p').remove('.field-link-target');
  $('p').remove('.field-xfn');
  $('p').remove('.link-to-original');
});
</script>
```

Being quite/really new with javascript I was wondering if a snippet like this can be even more optimized.

In example to something like this

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
$('p')array.remove('.field-css-classes', '.field-description', '.field-link-target', '.field-xfn', '.link-to-original');
});
</script>
```

(which, as you can tell, isn't working)

Comment: Do you want to use .remove(), as in remove the element from the DOM, or .removeClass(), as in remove a class from an element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Include the commas in the string....

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('p').remove('.field-css-classes, .field-description, .field-link-target, .field-xfn, .link-to-original');
});
```

example at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/B4q2a/

Comment: Thank you. I've tried this as well, but somehow, it isn't removing anything this way. Could you perhaps tell if I might have overlooked something else?

Comment: space doesnt work becuase then it reads parent to child, use commas as i showed in my answer, it's just simple css selector.  You can use css selectors like crazy in jQuery

Comment: also, you are removeing the class, whereas his example show he wants the element gone

Comment: @SpYk3HH, i had posted the correct answer.. then changed it because i thought he actually meant classes and have already reverted to my original one..

Answer (score 3):

jQuery selectors allow for [comma separated selections](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

```
jQuery(function ($) { //aliasing document.ready shortcut
    $('p').remove('.class1, .class2, .class3')
});
```

Comment: it's not even just about the commas, but yes this is right, jQuery allows for all types of css selection as your element selector.

Answer (score 2):

Really easy, use some simple CSS in your selector

```
$('p').remove('.field-css-classes, .field-description, .field-link-target, .field-xfn, .link-to-original');
```

Answer (score 0):

Since, in your example, you only removing classes of the p tags and you're using jquery, you can use jquerys [`removeClass` method](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/). According to the API, you can specify several classes there, like so:

```
$('p').removeClass('class1 class2 class3');
```

So, no commas seperating the class names and no leading dots.

Comment: He's not removing classes, he's removing elements by class name